# Какой из селекторов будет оптимальнее, в плане производительности?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Какая из этих процедур менее ресурсозатратна?

```
var content = $('.kb-content');
content.each(function () {
    if ($(this).data('parent-id') === targetId) {
        $(this).toggleClass('hidden');
    }
});
```

или

```
$('.kb-content[data-parent-id="' + targetId +'"]').toggleClass('hidden');
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89933/discussion-on-question-by-roman-andreev------).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery для выборки элементов использует библиотеку Sizzle. Эта библиотека разбирает переданную строку и для простых случаев использует стандартные функции `get*By*`, либо, в случае поддержки использует `querySelectorAll`.

Можно рассмотреть, что именно происходит в первом и втором случаях.

Первый случай:

1. `$('.kb-content');` - выборка **всех** элементов с классом `kb-content`
2. `content.each(function () {` - проход по каждому элементу
3. `if ($(this).data('parent-id') === targetId) {` - создание объекта jQuery, обращение к `data`, сравнение с параметром
4. `$(this).toggleClass('hidden');` - создание объекта jQuery, смена класса

---

Второй случай:

1. `$('.kb-content[data-parent-id="' + targetId +'"]')` - выборка элементов с классом `kb-content` у которых атрибут `data-parent-id` - имеет соответствующее значение
2. `.toggleClass('hidden');` - проход по каждому элементу и смена класса

---

Можно заметить как минимум два отличия:

1. разное количество элементов в выборке
2. отсутствие дополнительного условия.

Таким образом, если среди элементов с классом `kb-content` элементов с требуемым атрибутом будет сильно меньше, то вариант с выборкой по атрибуту будет выполняться быстрее, в силу того, что таких элементов будет меньше.

Также на скорость влияет множественное создание объектов `jQuery`.

[Пример тестов](https://jsperf.com/jquery-selector-by-class-with-each-vs-selector-by-attr), подтверждающих рассуждения выше.